# Ngrok not working correctly

Tags: ngrok

I've installed ngrok in Win 10 on a VM but I don't think it's working correctly.

To start it up and I use this command below to run it

> ngrok http -host-header="localhost:44368" 44368

and it looks like ngrok starts up ok, but when I put the https url given by ngrok into a browser this is what I see

[image]

Shouldn't I see something?

and in the ngrok console I see the get requests but no response times or response messages

[image]

same with the localhost:4040 page and every get request has a 0ms response time

[image]

Comment: One possibility might be that you are running an HTTPS only server. Check this site: https://ngrok.com/docs#bind-tls

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue running an **ASP.NET Core MVC Server**.

Upon lots of investigation, **disabling the https url** of my server seemed to work.

So essentially forcing it to only use http.
I had the problem using both http and https ngrok urls.

So for my ASP.NET core project in the `launchSettings.json`, ensure you only have the http option, **remove the https url** under your desired launch profile:

`"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001;"`

Comment: After a day of fighting ngrok 2.2.8 with .net core 2.1, this is what finally fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is still not works for you after @MikeDub's fix, please try this.
Go to properties of your startup project (api project) and untick,

> Enable SSL

in Debug section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As MikeDub mentioned above, I also found the exact explanation on Twilio documentation here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/csharp-dotnet-core#allow-twilio-to-talk-to-your-aspnet-core-application-with-ngrok

which indicates removing https App Url.